# Какие есть значения слова "актуальный"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Всем привет, форумчане!
Есть такое замечательное слово "актуальный". В каких значениях может использоваться это слово помимо того, которое указано в словарях Ожегова и Ушакова (важный, злободневный, насущный и т.п.)?
Можно ли его использовать как синоним слову "модный"?

Comment: В контексте все бывает. У вас какой-то пример есть?

Comment: Ну вот в индустрии моды часто слышу это слово: актуальный цвет, актуальный фасон, актуальная куртка и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: А допустимо ли употреблять это слово, когда говорим о том, что что-либо уместно, подходит в конкретной ситуации?

Comment: Смотря с чем сочетаете. Актуальный цвет, фасон - ок. Актуальная куртка - уже со скрипом. Актуальный пластырь или борщ - ну, видно, да? Только если нестандартный контекст (авангард, юмор...). То есть актуальный - слово для более абстрактных, нематериальных предметов.

Comment: Допустимо употреблять только с конкретизацией. Актуальный в данной ситуации борщ. Актуальный в данной ситуации пластырь.

Comment: Нашёл ещё в словаре Кузнецова такой вариант: "современный". Такой вариант ведь может употребляться только в случаях, когда что-либо "Стоящее на уровне своего века, отвечающее требованиям своего времени"? (Ну то есть, в третьем значении слова "современный" его же словаря)

Answer (score 2):

Иллюстрацией употребления слова "актуальный" в смысле близком к слову "модный" является известный ёрнический отрывок из Пелевина, каковой я не буду здесь приводить целиком, дабы не нарушить нормы политкорректности.  Можете загуглить слова из этого отрывка: "бывают активные, пассивные и актуальные". Дальше там у Пелевина идёт разъяснение.

Comment: Хахахаха, круто!